# How to stretch header & footer to the edges of the page?

Tags: html, css, header, footer

I am pretty new to HTML and CSS, and totally new to this forum. Currently I am working––as I learn––on a webpage that I want to send as an email. It's a pretty simple format with a header, sub header, body and footer. Although I am almost done with the page, I still understand very little of the coding. What I am stuck at right now is stretching the header & footer (solid colours) to the edges of the page (**top, left and right** for the *header & sub-header* and **left, right and bottom** for the *footer*).

I have naturally done a lot of research, looked into help forums and tried the tips found there, viz. resetting the css, setting margin, etc. Obviously I have been unsuccessful and therefore here I am.

Here's a snapshot of what the webpage looks like on an iPhone 5 over Google Chrome's Developer Tools
[image]

**HTML Header**

```
<head>
     <div class="header-background" style="margin-top:0;">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Vorstellung – Ether</title>
        //content
     </div>
</head>
```

**CSS Header**

```
.header-background {
  background: #899799;
  border: 0px solid #467813;
  border-radius: 0px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 20px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:0;
  top:0;
}

.sub-header {
  background: #23313B;
  border: 0px solid #467813;
  border-radius: 0px;
  color: #969696;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 20px;
}
```

**HTML Footer**

```
<footer class="email-footer">
    <div id="footer-content">
      <div id="wrapper">
         <p>
           <address>
                <div style="margin-left:20px">
                <span style="color: #DDD">Name<br> 
                Street<br>
                State<br>
                Country
                <br />
                <br />
                Copyright</span><br />
                </div>
          </address>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

**CSS Footer**

```
.email-footer {

}

#footer-content {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica", "sans-serif";
    color: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    background: #6e6e6e;
    padding: 50px 0px;

}
```

Any help and tips into improving the code in general would be much appreciated!

Thanks,
Ashish

**P.S.** I am working with Dreamweaver CS5.

Comment: left/top/right/bottom doesn't work with static postion .. why not simply use `width:100%` and remove all margin

Comment: also don't forget the margin,padding of the `body` that need to be removed. I think this is what you are missing

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that some styles of the body are set automatically.

So if you don't want to use the default values, you have to overwrite them.

In your case body has the margin style set to 8. So you will have to overwrite it with 0, if you don't want the margin in your code:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
}
```

The star element will overwrite all the elements in your html and set the margins to 0. Make sure that it is before everything, because if you change the margin somewhere later in your css, you don't want to overwrite it with 0.

Comment: why not simply specify this for body, html ?

Comment: You can specify it only for the body, but using it with a star will also overwrite any other tag default or already imported styles. So if you know that all of your content shouldn't have margins , unless you add it specifically for a tag, this way you are sure that you will overwrite all the default values.

Just be careful when you are using it, so you don't overwrite some other styles from separate .css files. If you call other css files, they will overwrite each other on the order you call them. So you should call the .css file containing *{} first.

Comment: you said it `Just be careful when you are using it, so you don't overwrite some other styles from separate .css files`. That's why in this case it's enough to specify in for the body to avoid conflict ;)

Comment: I just double checked. The * element will only override the default elements set by the browser. So if you set the margin on a different css file. It will not be overridden.

Comment: am totally ok with you. Am not saying you are wrong. I simply said that in this situation no need to use it as we can simply apply it to body and he will have footer/header stretched, that's all. Your solution will also work and you are free to keep it, i just commented ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Boris. I did use your tip. I had to fix some other issues I had ended up creating for myeslf, but eventually it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried playing with width and height in your CSS

**eg:**

```
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I haven't been back here in a long time. I had to drop that project the way I was approaching it because I wasn't reaching anywhere with it. I chose to go with MailChimp's solutions...

Answer (score -1):

Welcome. While you work on this HTML, it may be useful for you to know that various email templates are available from sites such as Mailchimp and CampaignMonitor. The templates are useful in the sense that these organisations have done much of the hard work for you, ensuring that the templates work in different email clients.

That said, if you set the CSS of the body to have zero margin and padding, then each content area can be given a width of 100%, to occupy the entire width of the page.

Going further, these content areas can be enclosed within a master container, which itself has a width of 100%. This way, you can reduce the width of your email later on, by simply changing that property value. The content areas then inherit that width.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @sassquad. It did help me a lot.

The reason I decided not to use sites like MailChimp because I am looking to achieve a completely customized template myself. Partly for my purpose, and partly to teach myself some basic coding.